# How do you thank a contributor for code that you use that was originally posted by a previous request by someone else?

Tags: discussion

Over several years I have used a large amount of VBA code sourced/copied from Stack Overflow and I feel the need to thank some of the people whose code I have included in my applications. I would like to send a thank you message to some of them whose existing posts have significantly helped me with specific problems or generally improved my applications.

Comment: You cant send a message directly to a user in SO, but you can up-vote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Pay it forward! Write some answers of your own, or ask some high-quality questions that will hopefully generate more good answers. Then when you have enough reputation you can thank them directly by upvoting them as suggested.

Comment: Independently of saying "thank you", please ensure that you are compliant with the Stack Overflow license ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). Basically, this requires that you give [**attribution**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) to the original source of the code/idea. That would mean, for example, adding a comment to your code including the name of the user who posted the answer and a link to it (use the "share" link underneath the answer to get a link).